# Looking for intentionally vulnerable nuget package for testing purposes

Tags: .net, security, nuget, cve

I am looking for one or more nuget packages that intentionally contain vulnerabilities. I want to test some security tools that should be able to pick up such nugets in my projects automatically and notify me, but I am having trouble finding any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the [GitHub Advisories Database](https://github.com/advisories), you can click on the [NuGet ecosystem](https://github.com/advisories?query=type%3Areviewed+ecosystem%3Anuget).

The [first advisory listed at the time I'm writing this](https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-w4m3-43gp-x8hx) lists 4 packages affected, although they're all runtime packages, so maybe you don't want to test with this package.

The [first advisory that is not part of the .NET runtime at the time I'm writing this](https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-838x-pcvx-6p5w) is for a package called Snappier, and [going to the package detail page, versions tab on nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Snappier#versions-body-tab), I can see that version 1.1.0 is listed as having a known vulnerability.

You might also be interested in [this advisory on Newtonsoft.Json](https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-5crp-9r3c-p9vr), which affects all older versions of the package, which is notable since Newtonsoft.Json is a very commonly used package, either directly or transitively though direct package dependencies. ([nuget.org org link to package details](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json#versions-body-tab))

Comment: Thanks, that should be enough for my experiments, though it is not exactly what I was looking for.